# single or multiple partition for 12.04?

Tags: installation, partitioning

Currently, I'm using ubuntu 10.04 with 5 partitions (boot, root, home, swap, usr). I'm going to **replace** 10.04 by 12.04 whereas my hard drive has 80GB. Should I create multiple partitions for 12.04 or single partition? If multiple, then how many and how much for each of them?

Note: I have to use virtualBox on 12.04.

Would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For home use: `/`, `/home` and `swap` on extra partitions should be enough.

Comment: Thanks Bobby for your quick reply. I'm going to make three partitions(root,home,swap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing this on a server, you can reap lots of benefits by creating multiple partitions ie: mail server, etc...

If this is for a desktop machine.  The only benefit is that you can install new O.S.'s over your existing / partition and keep your /home partition intact (this is my preference).  My setup would be something like:

/ - 15 Gigs (lots of extra room here, I've read about people getting away with < 5Gigs
swap - size of ram installed

/home - rest of HD space

Comment: Thanks a lot MCR. Ur answer is good enough. I'm going to create three partitions (root,swap,home).